# Jquery : Hide() and Show() elements after generating them with load()

Tags: jquery, methods, load, hide

Here is my code :

```
$(".feat").click(function () {
    $('#content').empty();

    $('#content').load('loaded/features.html', function() {
    $('.expla').hide();
    $('.g1,.g2,.g3,.g4,.g5,.g6').hide();
    $('.f1,.f2,.f3,.f4,.f5,.f6').hide();
    $('.w1,.w2,.w3,.w4,.w5,.w6').hide();
});
```

Here is features.html but it's not relevant :

```
    <div id="eruscont">
        <div id="erustyle">What I can do !</div>
        <div id="undercore">
            <div id="grinder">
            <div class="title grinder plus"><p>Grinder&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="image/add.png" /></p></div>
        </div>
            <div id="flyer">
            <div class="title flyer plus"><p>Flyer &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="image/add.png" /></p></div>
        </div>
            <div id="whack">
            <div class="title whack plus"><p>WHack &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="image/add.png" /></p></div>
        </div>
        </div><!-- Fin undercore -->
    </div><!-- Fin eruscont -->
<div id="schema"><div id="mainstuff"><p>Browse my main options, and you'll see what I'm able to do for you !</div>
    <div class="expla egrinder">
        <div class="explication g1">Define a path and kill mobs</div>
        <div class="explication g2">Smart movement/path system</div>
        <div class="explication g3">Loots, skins, gathers using ground mount</div>
        <div class="explication g4">Sells, buys, repairs, mails stuff</div>
        <div class="explication g5">Automatic spell casting highly customizable</div>
        <div class="explication g6">Computer still available for use when running</div>
    </div>
    <div class="expla eflyer">
        <div class="explication f1">Define a path and gather resources</div>
        <div class="explication f2">Kills, loots, skins, mines, Herbs</div>
        <div class="explication f3">Uses flying mount and Swiming mount</div>
        <div class="explication f4">Sells, buys, repairs, mails stuff</div>
        <div class="explication f5">Analyzes your skill level and pick up what you can have</div>
        <div class="explication f6">Computer still available for use when running</div>
    </div>
    <div class="expla ewhack">
<div class="explication w1">Use your character differently</div>
<div class="explication w2">Fly hack, Water Walk, Wall walk</div>
<div class="explication w3">Removes collision, AFK, falling and Lua protection</div>
<div class="explication w4">Auto Loot, Auto kick, tracking and morpher</div>
</div>        
</div>
```

.expla .g1 ...., f1..., w1... are elements located in features.html.
But they are not hidden by the hide() method, moreover later in my code I use show() method in order to make this elements appear thanks to different events.

I guess the problem is due to the fact that the result of load() isn't added to the DOM. But I don't know how to manage it. I'm not that good with jquery.

could you help me ?

Thanks for reading !

EDIT : I was wrong the hiding effect is working I just targeted the wrong elements. But after that loaded elements are not usable I mean for instance this is not working :

```
if($('.expla.eflyer').is(':visible') || $('.expla.ewhack').is(':visible'))
            {
                $('.expla').hide();
                $('#mainstuff').hide();
                $('.flyer img').attr({src: "image/add.png" });
                $('.whack img').attr({src: "image/add.png" });
                $('.flyer','.whack').addClass('plus');
                $('.g1,.g2,.g3,.g4,.g5,.g6').hide();
                $('.w1,.w2,.w3,.w4,.w5,.w6').hide();
                $('.grinder').removeClass('plus');
                $('.f1,.f2,.f3,.f4,.f5,.f6').hide();
                $('.expla.egrinder').show("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 3000,function () { callback("g")});   
                $('.grinder img').attr({src: "image/minus.png" });
                return false;
            }
```

This code is located in another js file which is a real big mess because of its lack of optimization but which is working properly, here is the entire page if you want to see how complicated it is :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.expla').hide();
    $('.g1,.g2,.g3,.g4,.g5,.g6').hide();
    $('.f1,.f2,.f3,.f4,.f5,.f6').hide();
    $('.w1,.w2,.w3,.w4,.w5,.w6').hide();

        // run the currently selected effect

    $(".grinder img").click(function () {
        if($('.grinder').hasClass('plus'))
        { 
            if($('.expla.eflyer').is(':visible') || $('.expla.ewhack').is(':visible'))
            {
                $('.expla').hide();
                $('#mainstuff').hide();
                $('.flyer img').attr({src: "image/add.png" });
                $('.whack img').attr({src: "image/add.png" });
                $('.flyer','.whack').addClass('plus');
                $('.g1,.g2,.g3,.g4,.g5,.g6').hide();
                $('.w1,.w2,.w3,.w4,.w5,.w6').hide();
                $('.grinder').removeClass('plus');
                $('.f1,.f2,.f3,.f4,.f5,.f6').hide();
                $('.expla.egrinder').show("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 3000,function () { callback("g")});   
                $('.grinder img').attr({src: "image/minus.png" });
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                $('#mainstuff').hide();
                $('.g1,.g2,.g3,.g4,.g5,.g6').hide();
                $('.grinder').removeClass('plus');
                $('.expla.egrinder').show("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 3000,function () { callback("g")});   
                $('.grinder img').attr({src: "image/minus.png" });
                return false;
            }   
        }
        else    
        {
            $('.grinder img').attr({src: "image/add.png" });
            $('.g1,.g2,.g3,.g4,.g5,.g6').hide();
            $('.expla.egrinder').hide("explode", 1500);
            $('.grinder').addClass('plus');     
            return false;
        }



    });

    $(".flyer img").click(function () {
        if($('.flyer').hasClass('plus'))
        {
            if($('.expla.egrinder').is(':visible') || $('.expla.ewhack').is(':visible'))
            {
                $('.expla').hide();
                $('#mainstuff').hide();
                $('.grinder img').attr({src: "image/add.png" });
                $('.whack img').attr({src: "image/add.png" });
                $('.grinder','.whack').addClass('plus');
                $('.g1,.g2,.g3,.g4,.g5,.g6').hide();
                $('.w1,.w2,.w3,.w4,.w5,.w6').hide();
                $('.flyer').removeClass('plus');
                $('.f1,.f2,.f3,.f4,.f5,.f6').hide();
                $('.expla.eflyer').show("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 3000,function () { callback("f")}); 
                $('.flyer img').attr({src: "image/minus.png" });
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                $('#mainstuff').hide();
                $('.f1,.f2,.f3,.f4,.f5,.f6').hide();
                $('.flyer').removeClass('plus');
                $('.expla.eflyer').show("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 3000,function () { callback("f")}); 
                $('.flyer img').attr({src: "image/minus.png" });
                return false;
            }   
        }
        else    
        {
            $('.flyer img').attr({src: "image/add.png" });
            $('.expla.eflyer').hide("explode", 1500);
            $('.f1,.f2,.f3,.f4,.f5,.f6').hide();
            $('.flyer').addClass('plus');   
            return false;
        }
    });

    $(".whack img").click(function () {
        if($('.whack').hasClass('plus'))
        {
            if($('.expla.egrinder').is(':visible') || $('.expla.eflyer').is(':visible'))
            {
                $('.expla').hide();
                $('#mainstuff').hide();
                $('.grinder img').attr({src: "image/add.png" });
                $('.flyer img').attr({src: "image/add.png" });
                $('.grinder','.flyer').addClass('plus');
                $('.g1,.g2,.g3,.g4,.g5,.g6').hide();
                $('.w1,.w2,.w3,.w4').hide();
                $('.whack').removeClass('plus');
                $('.f1,.f2,.f3,.f4,.f5,.f6').hide();
                $('.expla.ewhack').show("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 3000,function () { callback("w")}); 
                $('.whack img').attr({src: "image/minus.png" });
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                $('#mainstuff').hide();
                $('.w1,.w2,.w3,.w4').hide();
                $('.whack').removeClass('plus');
                $('.expla.ewhack').show("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 3000,function () { callback("w")}); 
                $('.whack img').attr({src: "image/minus.png" });
                return false;
            }   
        }
        else    
        {
            $('.whack img').attr({src: "image/add.png" });
            $('.expla.ewhack').hide("explode", 1500);
            $('.w1,.w2,.w3,.w4').hide();
            $('.whack').addClass('plus');   
            return false;
        }
    });


    // Grinder callbacks
    // Flyer callbacks
    //WHack callbacks       

        function callback(xlol) {
            var pif = "."+xlol+"1";
            var arg = xlol;
            $(pif).show("slide", 200, function () { call2(arg)});
        };

        function call2(xlol) {
            var pif = "."+xlol+"2";
            var arg = xlol;
            $(pif).show("slide", 200,function () { call3(arg)});    
        };      

        function call3(xlol) {
            var pif = "."+xlol+"3";
            var arg = xlol;
            $(pif).show("slide", 200,function () { call4(arg)});    

        };      
        function call4(xlol) {
            var pif = "."+xlol+"4";
            var arg = xlol;
            $(pif).show("slide", 200,function () { call5(arg)});    

        };      
        function call5(xlol) {
            var pif = "."+xlol+"5";
            var arg = xlol;
            $(pif).show("slide", 200,function () { call6(arg)});    

        };      
        function call6(xlol) {
            var pif = "."+xlol+"6";
            $(pif).show("slide", 200);  

        };


    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Set them as `display: none` in the HTML, and they won't show up (even briefly) on load.  Later `.show()` methods will still display them.

Comment: I also need the hide() methods to work cause later in my code if I want to show them, I also want to make it disappear onclick :p

Comment: They will...because at that point, they'll be loaded in the DOM and accessible.  You are trying to hide them before they are available.

Comment: Post edited, my problem changed if you want to try solve it again ^^

Answer (score 1):

A few problems with your code.

First of all your syntax is broken (I assume because you cut out some code for the sake of brevity).

That aside, you are trying to manipulate elements that don't exist when the DOM is created. You should have all the elements you want hidden beforehand, you could use:

```
.explication {
    display: none;
}
```

Then trigger them to show on an event using the [`$.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

```
$(document).on('click', 'someSelector', function() {        
    $('.someOtherSelector').show();
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answers, is there any way to keep it displayed, because I want it to work for users that don't use javascript at all.

Comment: Post edited, my problem changed if you want to try solve it again ^^

Answer (score 0):

you can try to set `$("YourElement").css("opacity","0")` or `$("YourElement").css("visibility","hidden")` or `$("YourElement").css("display","none")`

Comment: No it doesn't work, I had already tried this solution ^^

Thanks for you help :-)